# How to show Alert Dialog in the current activity after background task is completed

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to do a payment which will take more seconds to complete, I don't want the user to stay on the view till they see success message so once they hit the payment button in Background task On Pre execute I'm showing a popup saying "Processing your payment". Once the user clicks OK , they will be navigated to the different view.Once the background task is completed I want to show one more popup saying "Your payment was successful" in the current view.

Here is the code snippet,

```
private class payment extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
        payment() {
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            AlertDialog.Builder successDialog=new  AlertDialog.Builder(PayActivity.this);
            successDialog.setMessage("Processing your payment");
            successDialog.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                    Intent lResultIntent = new Intent();
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, lResultIntent);
                    finish();
                }

            });

            successDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

           // .....
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            Log.i("MSG","inside post");
            AlertDialog.Builder success = new AlertDialog.Builder(EditCardActivity.this);
                    success.setMessage("Your payment was successful");
                    success.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }

                    });
                    success.show();
        }
    }
```

**NOTE**

When I tried to run this code I was getting "E/UncaughtException: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@a38eb5 is not valid; is your activity running?"

So I googled and found

```
if(!isFinishing()) {success.show();}
```

but it didn't helped ,when I logged isFinishing() it printed as true.This question may be duplicate I have seen many Q/A similar to this exception. I tried most of it. Not sure what Im missing. Im struck here. Any suggestion or different approach would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in `onPreExecute` method because calling `finish()` method but `AsyncTask` is still running.

Before finishing current Activity on Ok Button click, call [AsyncTask.cancel](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel(boolean)) :

```
....
setResult(RESULT_OK, lResultIntent);
payment.this.cancel(true);
finish();
```

Also add check in `isCancelled()` before showing Alert from `onPostExecute`

```
if(!this.isCancelled()){
   // show Alert Here
}
```

Comment: getting java.lang.InterruptedException

Comment: Initially I tried giving the Toast in place of Alert dialog (onPostExecute), it is showing fine in the current view. But always the Alert dialog fails with this exception "E/UncaughtException: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@a38eb5 is not valid; is your activity running?"